# Is it possible to travel from London to India while on an ICT visa in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I have come to London on ICT short term visa which has multiple entry. My visa expires by September. I need to travel to India for a personal reason. Will there be any problem for my return travel?

Will there be any issues by immigration department in India?

Answer (score 3):

You will not have a problem getting back in to the UK so long as...

- Your ICT is still valid
- You do not flag up with an arrest warrant
- Your sponsor does not cancel the ICT

For your other question, if T2 visa holders have had problems entering India we would have heard about it.  Nothing has been reported, so you can expect no problems re-entering India based upon having a UK T2 (ICT).